# Some Arabic Letters are Missing in my PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, arabic

I have the following test code

```
Font arabic = FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simpo.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,16);

     try {
         Document d=new Document();
         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Sana'a\\Downloads\\test.pdf"));
         d.open();
         PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
         table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
         PdfPCell cell= new PdfPCell();
         cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
         Paragraph p= new Paragraph(jTextField1.getText(),arabic);
         Paragraph p2= new Paragraph("سناء علاء حسين",arabic);
         p.setAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
         p2.setAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
         cell.addElement(p);
         cell.addElement(p2);
         table.addCell(cell);
         d.add(table);
         d.close();
     }

     catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
```

which prints some text to a PDF file, but the PDF shows some missing letters.
For example:
when I write (بيداء عبد الله) in the jtext, the PDF shows

```
بياء عب الله
```

and (سناء علاء حسين) becomes

```
سناء علاء حسي
```

any solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a font that covers the full range of Arabic characters such as [Noto Naskh](https://github.com/jenskutilek/free-fonts/tree/master/Noto/Noto%20Naskh%20Arabic%20UI/TTF)

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me!!